# Using Google API 2, how do I upload files to a specific folder/collection?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, google-api

How do I upload any document using C# to a specific folder/collection? I am using Google Documents API 2.0. I know how to upload it to the root using the examples provided [here](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#UploadingDocs)

But how do I publish them to a particular folder?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the [.NET client source](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/src/documents3/documentservice.cs?r=1085) this is not implemented in the .NET client API provided by Google although it is [supported by the server-side API](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/documents/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UploadingToFolder). Basically this means you would need to implement this part yourself (until Google adds that to their .NET Client API/SDK).